# SQL window function and joins

Tags: sql, join, window-functions

My query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT 
    category_name, film_title, rental_count
FROM
    (SELECT 
        c.name AS category_name, f.title AS film_title, 
        COUNT(r.rental_date) OVER (PARTITION BY f.title) AS rental_count
    FROM 
        category c
    JOIN 
        film_category fc ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
    JOIN 
        film f ON fc.film_id = f.film_id
    JOIN 
        inventory i ON i.film_id = f.film_id
    JOIN 
        rental r ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id) t1
WHERE 
    category_name IN ('Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music')
ORDER BY 
    1, 2
```

And the results are as follows:

[image]

As you can see that the title of the movie is repeated, as you already know, it shouldn't. However, I can't understand why it is happening?

[image]

The answer should actually be as the picture above.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: One of your joins is multiplying the rows, take them out one at a time to see which. At a guess `rental` will cause problems without using `group by`, and multiple categories per film also possible

Comment: Just put a `distinct` after outermost `select` clause.

Comment: @KoushikRoy OP should **NOT** do `DISTINCT` without first understanding *why* multiple rows are being returned

Comment: :) Agree, sorry i assumed OP knows ones data.

Comment: You are not showing the real query. The query you are showing is invalid. There is a `GROUP BY` clause missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it happening?  That is what window functions do.  They don't reduce the number of rows.  That add new columns on existing rows (typically with data gathered from multiple rows).

You simply want an aggregation:

```
SELECT c.name AS category_name, f.title AS film_title, 
       COUNT(r.rental_date) as rental_count
FROM category c JOIN
     film_category fc
     ON fc.category_id = c.category_id JOIN
     film f
     ON fc.film_id = f.film_id JOIN
     inventory i
     ON i.film_id = f.film_id JOIN
     rental r
     ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
WHERE c.category_name IN ('Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music')
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks to all whom have helped answering my question! You guys are the best!